# Universal analytics added with Google Tag Manager shows real-time events but not historical

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm using Google Tag Manager to add Universal Analytics to a page and triggering an event with the JavaScript API. I'm able to the see the event being sent using GA Debugger and on the "Real-Time -> Events" page in GA but it never seems to make it to the "Behaviour -> Events" page (no filters or segments on). The page has been live for about 2 months so I would have thought the raw data would be well and truly processed by now. Is anyone able to provide any insight on why this is happening?

Comment: How long has it been since the event happened? That portion of GA is not realtime so it may take some time for it to show up

Comment: There should be 1000s events since the site has been live for at least 2 months (tracking form abandonment).

Comment: I should really have read your entire paragraph. My mistake.

Comment: Is it just event data that is not showing? Is your profile is migrated to UA

Comment: can you share the site?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Mine was resolved by changing the default tracking period from the default in the calendar (top right) on the Events Overview -page.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue. However I have now noticed that when I observe the events on the real-time -> events page, they are saved on the behaviours -> events page. Only if I see the events in real time first are they saved. This is bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this 'issue'.

I had integrated google tag manager into my site, and could see that the events were showing in realtime, but not in the historical data for behaviours/events.

The solution was, looking a the calendar. The historical events for me were, by default, looking at the previous months events. This makes sense then that the real time data I was seeing was not showing.

Below is the image of my realtime events coming through.
[image]

And here is an image of what I was seeing by default in the historical events view.

[image]

The day these images were taken was the 30th January 2017, as you can see, the calendar at the top right of the events graph is searching through December. Aha... makes sense now why the events are not showing right?

So I clicked the calendar, to change the date period being searched by the events graph and set it to my desired range, in this case, I set it to search for this Month (January), as I had only just implemented the tag manager logic.

[image]

Low and behold, after clicking apply on this new date range, the events appeared as I expected them to.

[image]

I'm unsure if this answers the OP's specific issue but this is what solved it for me.